# My attempt of proof of Baby Rudin exercise 4.25(a)

Tags: analysis

If $K$ is compact and $C$ is closed in $R^k$, prove that $K+C$ is closed.

My attempt of proof:

Let {$k_n + c_n$} be a convergent sequence in $K+C$ with limit $x$, where $k_n \in K, c_n \in C$, we need to show $x \in K+C$. Note that if {$k_n + c_n$} does not converge, then it is okay because the set can be closed if it does not have limit points. (**my question is** can I justify that any point  $x \in K+C$ can be expressed in the form of $k_n + c_n$?)

$R^k$ is a metric space, so the notions of compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent. K is given compact, thus, there is a convergent subsequence {$k_{n_p}$} of ${k_n}$ such that $\lim k_{n_p}=l \in K$. Also $\lim (k_{n_p} + c_{n})=x$, thus $\lim c_{n} = x-l \in C$ due to C closed. Thus $x = (x-l)+l \in K+C$.

My question is about I am not totally convinced by myself that $k_{n_p} + c_{n}$ can replace $k_{n} + c_{n}$ safely.

Comment: The axiom of choice guarantees such expansion $k_n+c_n$ is possible.

Comment: You can take the subsequence of $(k_n)$ that converges, say through indices $n_p$ but then you need to consider $c_{n_p}$ as well.